# Can't push local git repository: remote: error: GH001

Tags: git, github

I once had pushed (by mistake) a very large .zip file to this repository. I have since reverted the commit.  I have also removed all the branches except for master in this repository.  Is there anything I can do?  I am trying to push the local repository to GitHub and am getting this error:

```
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.        
remote: error: Trace: 4ac91eb4cfacb70239b2ef9a467ad457        
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.        
remote: error: File resource.zip is 154.23 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

If anyone has any ideas it will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history